# Как правильно менять расположение файлов в решении?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

В общем, у меня Visual Studio 2019 и TFS.
Когда я перемещаю ранее закомиченный файл в Visual Studio в другое место(папку), то он помечается плюсиком.

При этом старый файл не удаляется в системе контроля версий.

Как правильно делать перемещение файлов?

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/git_base/lessons/remove_or_move_files_in_git/theory_unit) Может подойдет...

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно просто drag&drop сделать в Solution Explorer для файла User.cs и в Team Explorer должно появиться:

- Folder1/Folder2/User.cs [added]
- <s>Folder1/User.cs</s>

Если это не работает, то через Explore переместить нужный файл, ну или git командой

```
git mv Folder1/User.cs Folder1/Folder2
```

Comment: Ну в таком случае разве не теряется вся история изменений файла?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Если в одной ветке сделали перемещение файла User.cs, а в другой ветке User.cs отредактировали, то история сохраниться и даже не будут конфликты, git поймет что User.cs был перемешен и сам аккуратно смёржит всё это дело. Главное чтоб в одном комите небыло перемещения и редактирования User.cs, тогда git может просто удалить и создать новый User.cs с потерейисторией и конфликтами при мерже.

Comment: Надо потестить.